# Problem with Vue /Javascript interpolation

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to interpolate a value of `photo` within Vue. Here is the components:

Explaination: We are defining a data set as null. We are then, performing a post method to a backend database where we get `photo,email,name` and `id`. Everything works fine until the  `photo` value. As you can see I performed a slice method on the string which removed unnecessary data. The output of this is just the file name.

```
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      photo: null,
      email: null,
      name: null,
      id: null
    };
  },
 created() {
this.axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/me", "body", {
        headers: axiosHeader
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.name = response.data.name;
        this.email = response.data.email;
        this.id = response.data.id;
        this.photo = "@/photodatabase/" + response.data.photo.slice(37, 56);
        console.log(this.photo);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

The value I got is `@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg` when I `console.log(this.photo)` which is the correct value. However when I try to interpolate it like:

```
<img v-else-if="photo != null" :src="photo"
  height="200px" width="200px" />
```

The image doesn't show. When I inspected element, you could see on the img tag that the value was `@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg` which was the correct value.

I tried interpolating like this:

```
<img v-else-if="photo != null" :src="`${photo}`"     
    height="200px" width="200px" />
```

and it still doesn't work. However when I didn't interpolate the value of `photo`, didn't use the v-bind shorthand `:` and just copied and pasted the value of `photo` to the `src` prop like this:

```
<img
          v-else-if="photo != null"
          src="@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg"
          height="200px"
          width="200px"
        />
```

Then it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the corresponding `v-if`?

Comment: @Pacholoamit! If my answer works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this isn't the correct URL `@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg`

You've wrote *"it still doesn't work"* so You get *"404 Not found"* error?

That link should lead to Your backend (static asset or Laravel controller).
`@` is rewritten by Webpack during compilation time to Your public url - it won't work as a dynamic path in runtime...

This code

```html
<img src="@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg" />
```

...should become something else after compilation. Inspect it.
It could be something like that:

```html
<img src="/static/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg" />
```

So if You didn't map `@` in `vue-router`, nor in Laravels `routes`, then You should change `@` in that link. You can try simply `/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg`

Comment: Here's picture if I [inspect element](https://imgur.com/a/wZNocaJ) I got no problem in the console as well. No errors.

Comment: I did a variety of checks. There's nothing wrong with the controller since when I did the same request via postman it works. It has something to do with the syntax I think or v-bind. Because if I don't v-bind it, and I just copy paste the link to the src prop directly. It renders.

Comment: And what URL did You use Postman? Because `@/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg` is just a tailing part, and I think the problem is with the beginning that cant be resolved by router...?

Comment: No, you were right in a way. It had something to do with webpack. I fixed it with the `require()` command. hahah. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Because is dynamic image src
must `photo` be absolute URL Like:  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg`
or

if in the same server

```
/photodatabase/041120_09_24_03.jpg
```

or you can easily send absolute URL on response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the require handler

```
<img v-else-if="photo != null" :src="require(${photo})"     
    height="200px" width="200px" />
```